# Advanced MySQL Joining. Speeding up query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

I have a list of users on my php application (using codeigniter). Each user may have completed a form with about 1000 or so total fields. The structure looks similar to this:

**users**

```
id|username|...
```

**completed_form_fields**

```
id|formid|userid|fieldkey|data
```

where field key is just a unique key for that particular form field, ie: "first_name"

I have a user search page where people can filter out specific users by the fields they chose (eye color, race, gender...) Then I need to display these fields so I would love (and currently have) an output like this:

```
$filteredmembers = array(
[0] = Object(
   [id] => 1
   [username] => kilrizzy
...
   [fields] => Array(
        [fname] => Jeff
        [gender] => Male
        ...
```

Currently my script is obviously taking forever since I query all the members who filled out this form, then loop through each one to query all of their fields. THEN filter those out based on criteria + page / offset.

I know there needs to be a way to join these together in one query I am not familiar with

Simplified version of my very slow code:

```
function get_members(){
    $this->db->select('u.*');
    $this->db->from('users AS u');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
        $members = $query->result();
        //Get fields from each user
        foreach($members as $mk => $mv){
            $fields = $this->get_form_fields($mv->id,1,true);
            $members[$mk]->fields = $fields;
        }
        return $members;
    }else{
        return false;   
    }
}
function get_form_fields($uid,$form,$values=false){
    $this->db->where('user', $uid); 
    $this->db->where('form', $form); 
    $query = $this->db->get('form_fields');
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
        $result = $query->result();
        return $result;
    }else{
        return false;   
    }
}
```

Comment: Your filter criteria should be part of a WHERE clause that is dynamically constructed from information in the completed_form_fields table. I can't imagine what you are attempting, but you might also need an INNER JOIN between the users and completed_form_fields tables.

Comment: @bfavaretto - added a sample of my query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way but it gets over expensive the more you add fields. The same thing occurs with many CMS that choose to store additionnal user data in that form.

You can get a working search SQL using this:

```
SELECT
    users.*,
    firstname.data AS firstname,
    lastname.data AS lastname,
    eyecolor.data AS eyecolor,

FROM
    users
    LEFT JOIN completed_form_fields AS firstname ON firstname.userid = users.id AND firstname.fieldkey = "firstname"
    LEFT JOIN completed_form_fields AS lastname ON lastname.userid = users.id AND lastname.fieldkey = "lastname"
    LEFT JOIN completed_form_fields AS eyecolor ON eyecolor.userid = users.id AND eyecolor.fieldkey = "eyecolor"

WHERE
    firstname.data LIKE '%searchdata%'
    OR lastname.data LIKE '%searchdata%'
    OR eyecolor.data LIKE '%searchdata%'
```

This method gets very big and expensive for the MySQL server the more you add tables. Therefore, i would recommend not to go more than 10-15 joins like that and then again, i'd profile it to make sure.

Comment: This looks like how I will need to do it. I was hoping there was a magic solution I was unaware of. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.username, f.formid, f.userid, f.fieldkey, f.data FROM user AS u
LEFT JOIN completed_form_fields AS f
ON f.userid = u.id


you should look at indexing your userid, index(userid), via phpmyadmin or sql file
```

[mysql-indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand the problem. You can use a single query to get all users, and all of their fields (basically, this is what Philip suggested):

```
SELECT u.username, f.* 
FROM user AS u
    INNER JOIN completed_form_fields AS f
    ON f.userid = u.id
ORDER BY u.id, f.fieldkey
```

To filter the results, add a `WHERE` clause with the conditions. For example, to only get data from `fieldkey`s 'k1', 'k2' and 'k3':

```
SELECT u.username, f.* 
FROM user AS u
    INNER JOIN completed_form_fields AS f
    ON f.userid = u.id
WHERE f.fieldkey IN ('k1', 'k2', 'k3')
ORDER BY u.id, f.fieldkey
```

Is this what you're looking for?