# fetch values from CIMY Extra User Fields

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using plugin "my theme login" and "CIMY Extra User Fields". i want to fetch the value of dropdown "state", the values are stored in table "wp_cimy_uef_data". I am using CIMY User Extra fields to allow my users to add lots of other information in their profiles, including state in dropdown. Now, i want to get the value of state specified for each user.

Comment: This question covers exactly the same field of mysql joining as we often see, please see my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809902/advanced-mysql-joining-speeding-up-query/8810012#8810012, it doesn't correspond to CIMY but it is the exact same thing you are facing

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use:

```
$value = get_cimyFieldValue(user_id, field_name);
```

http://www.marcocimmino.net/cimy-wordpress-plugins/cimy-user-extra-fields/documentation/